# Find string from table in cell in BiqQuery --> Query exceeded resource limits

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables in BigQuery:

- City List: Table: invertible-fin-XXX238.Reports.City
- StationionNames: invertible-fin-XXX238.Reports.Station

Most of the StationNames containing City Names. Now I want to extract the city from the Station Table. 
Here some example data:

- City: Berlin
- Stationname: inStore_Berlin_Alexanderplatz
- Stationname: Berlin Schönefeld Airport
- Stationname: Train Station Franchise Berlin

I tried the INSTR Function, but had no success (the INSTR works only with Legacy SQL and there I couldn’t use SUBSELECTS).

```
SELECT City,
INSTR((SELECT AdGroupName 
FROM [invertible-fin-XXX238.Reports.City]),City) AS Match 
FROM [invertible-fin-XXX238.Reports.Station]
```

Therefore I tried it with WHERE LIKE. Below the SQL Code:

```
SELECT a.City
FROM [invertible-fin-XXX238.Reports.City] a
CROSS JOIN [invertible-fin-XXX238.Reports.Station] b
WHERE b. Name LIKE '%' + a.City + '%'
GROUP BY a.City
```

But now the Query is too computationally intensive and I got the Error Code  “Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 18 or higher required.” back.

Could some please help me, writing a more resource friendly query.

Thanks in advance,
Philipp

Comment: can you explain/clarify your logic? why not to just select cities from report.city table?

Comment: The Stationname table does not contain the City. Therefore I need extract the City form the Stationname. But I cant easily extract the City from the Stationname, because there is no clear Stationname structure. My approach was to search for the City String in the Stationname and give back the Stationname and City. According to the example the perfect Outcome would be: 
Column1:  inStore_Berlin_Alexanderplatz; Column2: Berlin
Column1: Berlin Schönefeld Airport; Column2: Berlin
Column1: Train Station Franchise Berlin; Column2: Berlin
Column1: Train Station XXXX; Column2: n/a

Comment: can you make a sample bigquery public dataset? I would love to solve this query for you, but having data available would help me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are few of many possible versions for BiigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT city, station
FROM `invertible-fin-XXX238.Reports.Station` AS s
JOIN `invertible-fin-XXX238.Reports.City` AS c
ON REPLACE(LOWER(station), LOWER(city), '') <> LOWER(station)
```

or

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT city, station
FROM `invertible-fin-XXX238.Reports.Station` AS s
JOIN `invertible-fin-XXX238.Reports.City` AS c
ON LOWER(station) LIKE CONCAT('%',LOWER(city),'%')
```

You can remove LOWER() function if names of City are spelled in same case in both tables

While above versions look more straightforward - i would prefer below one as it allows control way you extract city from station -`r'([^ _]+)'` - you should all characters that you observe being delimiters in column station. So in this case you will extract only city when it is not part of longer name
Of course you should validate if you even need to worry of this

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH tokens AS (
  SELECT token, station
  FROM `invertible-fin-XXX238.Reports.Station` AS s,
    UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(LOWER(station), r'([^ _]+)')) token
) 
SELECT city, station
FROM tokens AS s
JOIN `invertible-fin-XXX238.Reports.City` AS c
ON LOWER(city) = token
```

Comment: Hello Mikhail, thanks a lot!!!! I will test the queries this week and give you feedback. Best, Philipp

Comment: It works perfectly. The Query with the extract from station -r'([^ _]+)' is much more computing friendly, than the other one.

Comment: Jepp - Done. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I also wonder how the performance for a sub-query would be in this case. For instance:

```
WITH City AS(
SELECT 'Berlin' As Name UNION ALL
SELECT 'Hamburg'
),
StationNames AS(
SELECT 'inStore_Berlin_Alexanderplatz' AS Name UNION ALL
SELECT 'Berlin Schönefeld Airport' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Train Station Franchise Berlin' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Train Station Hamburg' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Train Station Pluton'
)

SELECT
  Name StationName,
  (SELECT Name FROM City c WHERE LOWER(s.Name) LIKE CONCAT('%', LOWER(c.Name), '%')) city
FROM StationNames s
```

Or in your case:

```
SELECT
  Name StationName,
  (SELECT Name FROM `invertible-fin-XXX238.Reports.City` c WHERE LOWER(s.Name) LIKE CONCAT('%', LOWER(c.Name), '%')) city
FROM `invertible-fin-XXX238.Reports.Station` s
```

I know it's common sense for most databases that `JOIN` has better performance than sub-queries but BigQuery have lots of [different optimization techniques](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/inside-capacitor-bigquerys-next-generation-columnar-storage-format) for storing and querying data, I was curious to know how different the performance would be in this case.