# Join vs. Subquery

Tags: sql, join, subquery, google-bigquery, in-subquery

I have looking around for Joins vs Subquery in terms of resources and performance, and the answer seems to be platform dependent. But nothing seems to talk about them in terms of BigQuery.

When I expanded the range of my query to include 100s of GB, I came across a

```
Query Failed
Error: Resources exceeded during query execution.
```

I roughly have

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM table t1 WHERE 
(t1.a in (SELECT b FROM anothertable WHERE class='value') 
OR t1.a in (SELECT c FROM table2) )
```

I was wondering if JOINs would be better in BigQuery especially if I expand to TBs of data.

Comment: why not to actually try JOIN and shar eresult :o)

Comment: Or try `EXISTS` instead of `IN` since the semantics and execution are slightly different due to null handling.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I was going to do that if no one has done it before, but it requires a lot of time on my part to figure it out how to change the semantics.

Comment: if you are beginner and require help in constructing query with join  - just ask that specific question :o) your current question (which is - I was wondering if JOINs would be better in BigQuery especially if I expand to TBs of data.) is too generic

Comment: @ElliottBrossard If `EXISTS` is not the same as `IN` unless I do something like `EXISTS (SELECT c FROM table2 WHERE t1.a=c)`. Why does the null handling matter?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I will ask for help if I need help, but I am just unsure of the performance quality with join vs subquery in the space of BigQuery.

Comment: sure. you are the boss of this post :o) and can tailor it the way you need

Comment: I kinda "asked" the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409424/find-string-from-table-in-cell-in-biqquery-query-exceeded-resource-limits), hopefully OP will share results :). I also wonder in BQ which is preferable but for what I found in my day to day use is that it really depends. BQ has lots of advanced and complex optimization going on behind the scenes, looks like it's hard to tell that there's a winner after all (maybe you should try different approaches and conclude which is working best for you). I found queries where JOIN is better but also queries where subquery won.

Comment: For my cases, JOIN tended to use significantly more resources since I still needed WHERE to differentiate which results I needed, and the performance and resources depended on the WHERE. Otherwise, I think I will keep the subqueries for readability.

Comment: Try `DISTINCT`, see answer below

Answer (score 3):

Note the difference between this query and the next one:

1)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNTIF(author IN (
   SELECT author 
   FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_01` 

))
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_01`
```

2)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNTIF(author IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT author 
   FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_01` 
))
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_01`
```

It's a silly query - and both should return `157893170`. Nevertheless 1) has taken more than 8 minutes to run (so far), while 2) ran in 36 seconds.

The secret? When doing an `IN()`, make sure to remove duplicates with a `DISTINCT` - if not there will be a lot of rows to JOIN that don't change the result at all.

```
// TODO(gcp): This could be a BigQuery optimization.
```

Comment: That is an interesting find, but I still get the same error, mostly because my subqueries already query tables that should host mostly distinct rows.

Comment: How big are these tables? Can you do a SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT) from these tables? Maybe the OR is throwing it off - what if you did an union of the 2 tables so the IN runs only once over one list?

Comment: About 45000 distinct with all the or statements. I will see how the union changes anything, though I just think the resource blow up has to do with the main query of SELECT. I will post later on UNION.

Comment: And the UNION makes it blow up on resources as well.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder, have you tried Elliott's suggestion of using `EXISTS`?

Something like:

```
WITH table1 AS(
SELECT '1' as user, 1 AS id UNION ALL
SELECT '2' AS user, 2 as id UNION ALL
SELECT '3' AS user, 3 as id
),
anothertable AS(
SELECT '1' AS user, 'value' AS class , '4' AS c UNION ALL
SELECT '2' AS user, 'value2' AS class, '2' AS c UNION ALL
SELECT '4' AS user, 'value' AS class, '3' AS c UNION ALL
SELECT '5' AS user, 'value2' AS class, '5' as c
),
table2 AS(
SELECT '4' AS c UNION ALL
SELECT '2' AS c UNION ALL
SELECT '3' AS c UNION ALL
SELECT '5' as c
)

SELECT
  t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE TRUE
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM anothertable ta WHERE (class = 'value' AND t1.user = ta.user))
OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.user = t2.c)
```

Does it exceed resources?

Comment: From BigQuery, I get `Error: Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.`

Answer (score 0):

I have around 251936 records in Maria DB,

Now the query I write using Subquery

SELECT COUNT(*) AS cartCount FROM CART WHERE CHANGED_DATE <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)   AND ID IN (     SELECT CART_ID     FROM CHANNEL     WHERE CHANNEL_ID = 'oneshop'   ) LIMIT 0, 1000  1 row(s)

returned    23.180 sec / 0.000022 sec

and by using JOIN

SELECT COUNT(*) AS cartCount FROM CART JOIN CHANNEL ON CART.ID = CHANNEL.CART_ID AND CHANNEL.CHANNEL_ID = 'oneshop' WHERE CART.CHANGED_DATE <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) LIMIT 0, 1000

1 row(s) returned   2.565 sec / 0.000019 sec

check the difference, 23.180 sec -> 2.565 sec